# OperationalError: "Unknown MySQL server host"

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I am trying to connect to AWS Database with help of **MySQldb**.

When I connect it with the config:

```py
DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "host": "xxxxx-xxxx.xxxxxx.us-west-x.xxxx.amazonaws.com",
        "port": 3306,
        "user": "<name>",
        "passwd": "********",
        "db": "<db_name>",
        "charset": "utf8",
    }
}
```

Using **MySQLdb**:

```py
def get_mysql_connection(dbname="default"):
    """ 
    Returns a connection to database specified in settings 
    by the given dbname.
    """
    config = settings.DATABASES[dbname]
    return MySQLdb.connect(**config)
```

I am getting this error:

```py
in get_mysql_connection
    return MySQLdb.connect(**config)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 84, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 164, in __init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (2005, "Unknown MySQL server host 'xxxxx-xxxx.xxxxxx.us-west-x.xxxx.amazonaws.com' (-3)")
```

I am able to connect to the database using MySQL Workbench with the same credentials on the same network but getting the error when connecting in Python.

Where should I make changes to get it working?

Comment: are you able to ping to this server DNS from your command prompt...??

Comment: Yes, I am able to do that

Comment: Is MySQL server reachable from the machine where you are running python application?

If you have telnet installed, try 

`telnet <mysql_host> 3306`

Is it able to connect?

Comment: It might be possible that inbound connection for port 3306 in AWS security group is blocked from your local machine. If you are not able to connect on port 3306, you might want to check the security group on AWS.

Comment: Yes, I think it is reachable as I am able to connect on MySQL workbench.

Comment: please try connecting with the public IP inplace of hostname...

Comment: How should I get the public ip name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a workaround for this. The problem that I figured out was related to network speed/bandwidth.

When connecting from **MySQL Workbench**, It does not have any timeout or has a very high timeout for the query so it gets connected and shows the tables and DB query can be performed.

But in Python, it has a very low timeout for connection with the host. So, I increased the timeout in the **config** by adding the param **`connect_timeout`**.

Now, the config looks like this:

```py
DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "host": "xxxxx-xxxx.xxxxxx.us-west-x.xxxx.amazonaws.com",
        "port": 3306,
        "user": "<name>",
        "passwd": "********",
        "db": "<db_name>",
        "connect_timeout": 180,
        "charset": "utf8",
    }
}
```